# Keep library class untouched by ProGuard

Tags: proguard

How to tell ProGuard to do not change in any way specific class/package?

Do not optimize it, do not shrink it, do not obfuscate, do not do anything at all with it, just look but don't touch?

`-keep class com.example.** { *; }` seems to shrink private/unused constructors/methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should try -dontoptimize & -dontshrink in your configuration file and then use allowshrinking and allowoptimization with your keep option wherever you want  this to apply with your class/package.